# bash script. run command with counted numbers and names

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i try to code a script. it ask me how many "anything" you want? and i answered with a number like 10

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter some input: "
read input
```

now I like perform a command 10 times include numbers from 001 to 010
for example i get the right numbers with:

```
seq -f "%03g" 1 $input
```

but how can I execute now commands using this number like:

```
command anyname-001 -some -parameter
command anyname-002 -some -parameter
command anyname-003 -some -parameter
```

....

thanx for help

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash:

```
for ((i=1;i<=$input;i++)); do
  printf -v number "%03d" "$i"
  echo command anyname-${number} -some -parameter
done
```

If everything looks okay, remove `echo`.

Comment: Than you !! running well !!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a for loop over the range. That should do the trick.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter some input: "
read input

for number in `seq -f "%03g" 1 $input`
do
  command anyname-${number} -some -parameter
done
```

Comment: Than you !! running well !!

Answer (score 1):

One line (well, formally two):

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'command anyname-%03d -some -parameter\n' $(seq $1)
```

Call the script as:

```
$ script 10
command anyname-001 -some -parameter
command anyname-002 -some -parameter
command anyname-003 -some -parameter
command anyname-004 -some -parameter
command anyname-005 -some -parameter
command anyname-006 -some -parameter
command anyname-007 -some -parameter
command anyname-008 -some -parameter
command anyname-009 -some -parameter
command anyname-010 -some -parameter
```